# css to have background image strech to fill window. Don't care about aspect ratio

Tags: css, background

I have looked and looked and I simply do not find an answer.

What I want to do is take an image (png) and have it stretch to fill a background completely no matter the size of the window.

Everything I have tried will either crop the image or not stretch the image.  I cannot find css code that will stretch and/or compress an image to fill the background without cropping or requiring scroll bars.  As it implies in the title: I don't care if the aspect ratio gets really weird.

Answer (score 0):

`background-size` property is what you're looking for here:

```css
section {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/200/200) 50% 50%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

section#short {
  height: 50px
}

section#tall {
  height: 150px
}
```

```html
<section></section>
<section id="short"></section>
<section id="tall"></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
   background-size: contain;
```

it would be better if you use it. It will maintain the aspect ratio as well to a extent and you can use

```
   background-position: center; //read about it to make a part of your image visible
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: The image repeats many times.  If I add  background-repeat: no-repeat; then I get one small image (I think that's weird).  The original image is 2048x1366

Comment: Actually what contain does is it will try to show the whole image within the given div that is why it is showing a small image to you

Answer (score 0):

You can do using following property.

> background-repeat: no-repeat;
>
> background-size: cover;

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Outside In Viewer Technology ActiveX Sample</title>
  </head>
 
 <body style=" background-image: url('https://cdn-4.motorsport.com/images/amp/6bpWJBL2/s6/f1-hungarian-gp-2018-kimi-raik.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat;  background-size: cover;">

  <input type="button" onclick="btn_click_openfile()" value="Open File">
  <input type="button" onclick="btn_click_searchfile()" value="Search File">
  <input type="button" onclick="btn_click_searchnext()" value="Search Next">

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The image I am using is 2048x1366. If I use your css and resize the window to 463x408 then I get the entire image but it is not stretched vertically.